# how to get company details from mca.gov.in using PHP / CURL / Javascript etc..?

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I want to get company details from 
http://mca.gov.in/DCAPortalWeb/dca/MyMCALogin.do?method=setDefaultProperty&mode=31

Only the second input CIN/FCRN/LLPIN/FLLPIN  is required . 
example CIN : U01400DL2014PTC267361

I have the following code :

```
<?php
$url=http://mca.gov.in/DCAPortalWeb/dca/MyMCALogin.do?method=setDefaultProperty&mode=31';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);     
?>
```

I looked at the source of that page, and don't find any form in that page. It seem to be using JavaScript to retrieve company information after clicking on "Submit" button.

So, I don't understand how to input that CIN in the form and retrieve the company details using PHP.

Suggest me any method that can help in this case.

Comment: Hi, Have you found the way to get company details.

Comment: Any progress you made here ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a form where data is sending, look:

```
<form action="/DCAPortalWeb/dca/CompanyMaster.do" method="post" name="CompanyMasterEditForm">
```